# how to return Custom Json in http 404 ASP.NET Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

WebApiConfig.cs

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "search/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //JSON RESPONSE SETTING 
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
```

ReplyController.cs

```
public class ReplyController: ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage getReply()
    {...}
 }
```

and I write json return custom error code below:

```
401 Bad Request - {meta:{code:401, msg='invalid params'}}
```

I want to write json return code for 404 http status.

whhere I write? controller class? webconfig.cs? Global.asax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a couple options on where to write that code:

1. You can add a global filter that handles the **OnError** condition, and then have that filter return back a proper JSON response. There are a few different examples of that if you google around.
2. What I like to do, is have a custom **BaseApiController** class that has an ExecuteRequest method that takes a lambda delegate as it's parameter, and then inside the ExecuteRequest method body I can do all my setup before I call the delegate and my teardown and error handling after I call the delegate. I went this way b/c I use SimpleInjector as my DI framework and it was a pain to get custom filters to get DI injected, AND run in the order I wanted them to.

Let me know if that makes sense, but I think that would work well for you here, b/c then you could just handle that in a try/catch and be good to go.